# Создание и сохранение списка изменений объектов

Tags: c#, .net

Доброго времени суток!

Столкнулся с задачей сохранения списка изменений в коллекции объектов на диск.

```
public class Foo
{
    public string WindowColor;
    public int FontSize;

    // какие-то составные типы...
    public Car Car;            
}
```

Есть коллекция таких объектов (около 1000 элементов)

```
List<Foo> Foos;
```

Элементы этой коллекции ежедневно редактируют пользователи, сетевые сервисы,  ...
Необходимо сохранять изменения этой коллекции на диск, чтобы в любой момент можно было открыть файл с диска на нужный день и просмотреть изменения.

Я думаю использовать бинарную сериализацию коллекции изменений, т.к. быстрее и нет необходимости открывать в ручную файл.

```
public class ChangeFoo
{
    DateTime TimeStamp;       //время изменения

    public Foo Foo;           //старый объект
    public Foo FooNew;        //новый объект

    //методы по вычислению изменений  Foo->FooNew
}
```

При каждом изменении я наполняю такую коллекцию.

```
List<ChangeFoo> ChangeFoos;
```

Мне было бы удобно при наполнении коллекции в памяти сразу же писать 1 изменение на диск.
Но я столкнулся с тем что сериализовать нужно ВСЮ коллекцию, чтобы потом без исключений ее десериализовать с диска. 
Грубо говоря если сериализуешь по 1 объекту ChangeFoo, то при загрузке не получается извлечь все объекты так:

```
ChangeFoos= (List<ChangeFoo>)binFormat.Deserialize(fStream);
```

Т.е. если у меня будет 10000 изменений за день я для сохранения след. изменения обязан буду перезаписать весь список (пусть и в бинарном виде).

Подскажите как правильно сохранять такие коллекции и может в самой структуру ChangeFoo хранить пару имя измененного свойство и его значение, чтобы потом через рефлексию можно было присвоить значение свойству?

Comment: Исправьте форматирование.

Comment: если бы объекты имели фиксированный размер, то можно было бы

Comment: Для решения таких проблем (запись и извлечение в удобном виде) и придумали базы данных. Без БД придется придумывать собственные механизмы: сохранять файлы по одному в каталог, а потом считывать каталог полностью; специальный формат и т.п.

Comment: Насчет БД согласен. Программа старая, доживает последние дни  и там нет БД, но придется поддерживать определенное время.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не мучайтесь и используйте [LiteDb](http://www.litedb.org/) - это простая и легкая в использовании `NoSQL Database`, которая хранит все данные в переносимом файле. Есть поддержка индексов, возможность сохранить файлы, `Linq`, fluent mapping и прочие приятные мелочи.

Comment: Спасибо, выглядит прикольно, одно но проект мой писался человеком, который использовал структуры заместо классов, непонятно зачем)). я боюсь что со структурами работать не будет

Comment: +1 В принципе для нужд автора и SQLite подойдет.  @Aldmi для текущей задачи хватит одной таблицы с одним столбцом в которой будут храниться сериализованные `ChangeFoo`

Comment: для SQLite все таки сервер БД нужен, тогда я бы уже все на БД переписал через EF.

Comment: @Aldmi структуры тоже сохраняются нормально.

Comment: спасибо большое !!!

Comment: @Aldmi Для SQLite, сервер не нужен, да и не существует.